# How to add HTML text to every page using Google Optimize?

Tags: google-optimize

I would like to add a few lines of HTML to every single product page on my website.

However, it only works on one URL. I'm really sure my URL targetting is setup correctly.

I've selected an element on the page – and used "HTML" and "Insert" to add the code to the page. However it doesn't work on every page.

Comment: Could you please share some relevant details? What is your css selector for the modification? Is it general, or maybe a product specific id is captured by Optimize? (Have you checked in debug mode, if the experiment is executed on other product pages?)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually the debug mode tells me the test works on each relevant page, but the actual change does not show. I've selected a div (product information box) and simply dropped my code in there.

Comment: Looking at the editor window during the setup of the test, can you identify the CSS selector, that is used by Optimize? Is it div.someClass? Or maybe div#someID is used?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

It's #product-details>div:nth-of-type(5)